# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offset() is undefined when my target is append element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offset() is undefined

Before this I made the parent `<div>` with id `contentMessage` I get all data from the database and I made a jQuery operation to loop that data in success response I loop element a `</div class"alert">` and then I append it into my parent `<div id="contentMessage">`. I get the error when I want to auto scroll into latest alert which append.

```js
//my append element into `<div id=contentMessage>`
$.ajax({
  url: "<?= $apiEndpoint ?>/message/",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    outlet_from: outlet_from,
    outlet_to: outlet_to,
    from: id_from,
    to: id_to
  },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(res) {
    let a = 0
    let resCount = res.length
    window.count = resCount -= 1

    if (res.length == 0) {
      var append = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "parent_message p-2",
      }).append(
        $('<div/>', {
          'class': 'text-center',
          text: 'Tidak Ada Pesan'
        })
      )

      $("#contentMessage").append(append)
    }
    $.each(res, function(key, val) {
      var d = new Date(res[a].created_at)
      if (d.getMinutes() < 10) {
        var times = d.getHours() + ":" + "0" + d.getMinutes()
      } else {
        var times = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes()
      }

      if (res[a].from === <?= $user_id ?>) {
        if (a == window.count) {
          window.message = $('<div/>', {
            "class": "alert alert-primary alert-dismissible alertFrom ",
            "id": "resMessage",
            text: res[a].message
          }).append($('<small/>', {
            text: times
          }))
        } else {
          window.message = $('<div/>', {
            "class": "alert alert-primary alert-dismissible alertFrom",
            text: res[a].message
          }).append($('<small/>', {
            text: times
          }))
        }

        var append = window.message
      } else {
        if (a == window.count) {
          window.message = $('<div/>', {
            "class": "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible alertTo",
            "id": "resMessage",
            text: res[a].message
          }).append($('<small/>', {
            text: times
          }))
        } else {
          window.message = $('<div/>', {
            "class": "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible alertTo",
            text: res[a].message
          }).append($('<small/>', {
            text: times
          }))
        }

        var append = window.message
      }

      $("#contentMessage").append(append)
      a++
    })
  }
})
}
```

This is my scroll code:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $('.contentMessage').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#resMessage").offset().top
  }, 3000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: you should put the scroll code into the ajax success callback, so you can be sure that the element #resMessage was created

Comment: thank you so much for your answer , it works to my code

Comment: I´m glad it helped you, I would approchiate it when you would mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place your "scrollfunction" below the code where the element with id resMessage is created. Otherwise (in your example if the ajax-response and the element creation takes longer than 2000ms the element will not be existent yet and you will see error you described)

```
success:function(res){

  ...

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.contentMessage').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#resMessage").offset().top
    }, 3000);
  }, 2000);
}
```

probably the timeout isnt even required then anymore ;)